# exchangeService.FindItems vs exchangeService.FindAppointments methods

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I would like to have a deeper understanding about when to use  `exchangeService.FindItems` and `exchangeService.FindAppointments` methods in EWS  . In addition to that what is considered as Item and what is considered as Appointment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use FindAppointments when dealing with Calendar Items, the difference between the two is that FindAppointments will expand recurring Appointments/meetings where FindItems will just return the underlying Item without expansion. If your using Office365 then using the Graph API is probably a better option as EWS is now legacy and you may find it harder to use and support in the future.